# Web app - storing and requesting data when moving between different pages

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have a web application where it consists of 3 main pages. These pages are all accessible from a menu bar at the top. 
The 1st page is a search page, where the user searches for a customer. Customers matching the search criteria populate a table using an AJAX call and the user selects one of them, going to the 2nd page.
The 2nd page displays information on a customer when they have been found using the 1st.
The 3rd page contains additional information about the customer.

I have two questions about this architecture.

(1) When the user selects a single customer from the table in the first, how can I navigate to the second page where all the information for that customer is displayed? I have a template for the page with empty tables etc., and a database of the customers' info. How can I both hyperlink to the 2nd page from the 1st AND pull data from the database to populate the tables?

(2) When a user navigates to the 3rd page, for example, from the 2nd, how can I retain the state of the 2nd page so that when they go back to it using the menu bar the page still contains all the information of that most recently searched customer?

Comment: I think that client-side programming won't be enough for your needs, you should look for "Sessions" in the server-side language you are using, that way you will easily keep data integrity between pages for a user that is surfing your site.

Comment: Thanks. We are using PHP - are sessions the way to go?

Comment: yes, i suggest you to do so. Take a look at this page for a fast brief about it: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp . with a little google you will find loads of examples to achieve what you need easily.

Comment: Cheers for that. I guess that's what I need!! A quick question, do I put that PHP session code into my HTML pages? I always thought best practice was to separate concerns, HTML in one file, JavaScript in another etc.

Comment: keeping your code segments apart it's always the best choice when possibile, the best thing you could do is to manage the session in a .php file that you will "include" in all pages, this way everytime you have to change it you will just need to modify the code in just one place.